# Is there an R function in Shiny for if else statement

Tags: r, shiny

I have 2 condition for arrays to be displayed  in shiny. I tried with the below code in R shiny but not the output

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Value of x",choices = 
c("Array1","Array2"))),
  mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
            textOutput("message")
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$message <- renderUI(
{
  if(input$x == "Array1")
  {
    renderTable(array(1:20, dim=c(4,5)))
  } else 
    {
    if(input$x == "Array2")
    {
    renderTable(array(1:25, dim=c(5,5)))
    }
  }
  }
 )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there an issue in the code. Please advice

Answer (score 3):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(selectInput("x","Value of x",choices = 
                                     c("Array1","Array2"))),
        mainPanel(h6("Here it is"),
                  tableOutput("message")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$message <- renderTable(
        {
            if(input$x == "Array1")
            {
                   array(1:20, dim=c(4,5))
            } else 
            {
                if(input$x == "Array2")
                {
                   array(1:25, dim=c(5,5))
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. You mixed up multiple UI Types. RenderUI and textOutput for example.
2. You use renderTable inside renderUI. RenderUI needs a `tableOutput` to display correctly. But I think you don´t need it anyway, because all you want is to display the table.
3. It is far more common in R to use `data.frames` or `matrix` instead of multidimensional arrays.

Comment: perfect thanks. But still I am not convinced with you the definitions of renderUI and renderTable. Cannot we use RenderUI for textOutput?

Comment: no, you have to use the corresponding type to display the output correctly. `textOutput` also only works for text like "this is an array", but will not work to display multidimenional data. In general I would ALWAYS use `renderUI` and `uiOutput` in favor of `textOutput`, since you can use HTML text with the `uiOutput`function. If my answer was helpful, please accept it :-)